# Prometheus http request completion rate?

Tags: java, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus, and trying to achieve http request completion rate in x minutes. For instance, if controller had 200 requests within 5 minutes and out of 200 requests, only 100 requests were "processed", I am expecting 0.5.

I can get total number of requests using `increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{service="myservice"}[5m])` or any custom Counter I implement. However, I am not sure how to get total number of completed requests **out of those requests**. Is there a built in function or metrics I can use? I am not sure if this is possible to achieve with Prometheus.

Comment: What do you mean by *processed* ? Do you have a HTTP status code from the response ?

Comment: Yes. Processed as in returned any http status code.

Comment: Then why don't you just check for request with return code betwen 200 and 400 (exluded) ? The metric `http_server_requests_seconds_count` should include a label with the code.